# Get selected value from dropdownlist using JQuery and save it in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I was able to save dropdownlist value to database before I add the Jquery code:

```
  <select asp-for="CategoriesId" id="CategoriesId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CategoriesId">
                                        <option value="0">select</option>
                                    </select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CarMake").hide();
    $('#CategoriesId').on('change', function () {
        if (this.value == '2')           
        {
            $("#CarMake").show();
        }
        else {
            //$(this).val()
            //$('#CategoriesId').data();
           // $('#CategoriesId').val($(this).val());
            $('#CategoriesId').text();
        }
       
    });
});
```

I tried all command

Null reference error in this asp.net backend code

```
 ViewData["CategoriesId"] = new SelectList(_context.Categories, "Id", "Titel",ad.CategoriesId);
```

Comment: A few things. If you had working code that you changed, how about showing us that also? I'm not familiar with asp.net-mvc but unless there is some dark magic ju ju that it's doing behind that scenes, there is no possible way the code you have posted save **anything, anywhere**. Maybe you could provide an [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/nSMhi0

Controller and View Model

```
public class MyCategory
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
public class FatimaViewModel
{
    public IList<MyCategory> CategoryList { get; set; }
    public int SelectedCategory { get; set; }
}
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index17(FatimaViewModel vm)
    {
        //put breakpoint here
        var selectedItem = vm.SelectedCategory;
        FatimaViewModel vmOriginal = PopulateViewModel();
        return View(vmOriginal);
    }
    public ActionResult Index17()
    {
        FatimaViewModel vm = PopulateViewModel();
        return View(vm);
    }
```

View

```
@model WebApplication2.Controllers.FatimaViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Index8</title>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#CarMake").hide();
            $('#CategoriesId').on('change', function () {
                if (this.value == '2') {
                    $("#CarMake").show();
                }
                //got rid of unnessary code
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>Select cateogry 2 to show text</div>
        <div id="CarMake">This is shown when second category selected</div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.SelectedCategory, new SelectList(Model.CategoryList, "CategoryId", "CategoryName"), "--select--",
                                    new { id = "CategoriesId" })
            <input type="submit" value="Go" />
        }

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```